# How to make my car or object move on smoothly

Tags: unity-game-engine

How can I move an object like car over this without falling and I want it to stay connected and run or walk smoothly over the input so what thing I should use here in unity engine so here is the image

[How to stay connected to land](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9IqJ.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Raycasting? Hard to give a quality answer when you provide virtually no context. Are you using physics? You could increase the vehicle speed.

Comment: I am using rigidbody 2d, wheel joint , circle collider so can you tell how do I use ray cast